# MongoDB C++ Driver installation on Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, mongodb, boost, boost-filesystem

It's been 2 days I'm trying to install the driver C++ of MongoDB but I keep running into the same mistake ( in Mac OS X environnement )

```
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:24,
             from /opt/local/include/boost/filesystem/convenience.hpp:22,
             from pch.h:83,
             from pch.cpp:18:
/opt/local/include/boost/filesystem/config.hpp:16:5: error: #error Compiling Filesystem      version 3 file with BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION defined != 3
In file included from util/goodies.h:22,
             from pch.h:161,
             from pch.cpp:18:
 util/concurrency/mutex.h: In function 'boost::xtime mongo::incxtimemillis(long long int)':
```

Before installing the lib ( by doing "scons" ), I installed pcre and boost via portmac ( sudo port install boost ).

Any ideas ? I'm really stuck right now..

Thx guys.

Comment: What version of `boost` did you install?  And what version of the C++ driver are you trying to compile?  It looks like you may have installed an incompatible version of boost from ports.

Answer (score 3):

You need downgrade the boost library to 1.45 or earlier version to build the mongodb, because it depend on the boost::filesystem v2, but the latest boost (after v1.46) is using boost::filesystem v3 by default.

http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_46_0.html

> Filesystem:
>     Version 3 of the library is now the default.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and downgrading to boost 1.45 got it compiled for me (thanks [Flier Lu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486038/flier-lu)).   I use MacPorts to install Boost; here's instructions on how to downgrade:

https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort